# Add external scripts int admin header in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1

i need to add the following in the admin section head tag:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
<script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js" async=""></script>
<script>
  var OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
  OneSignal.push(function() {
    OneSignal.init({
      appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    });
  });
</script>
```

i know how to add local scripts , but any idea how to add remote scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code in your layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js" src_type="url"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Comment: THAAAAANK UUU U

Answer (score 0):

This will working in 2.2.2 or updated versions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="vendor-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Your Title</title>
        <css src="Namespace_Modulename::css/component.css"/>
        <link src="Namespace_Modulename::js/custom-file-input.js"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Your Title</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```